# Can I have another 2 groups in a group in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a Stored Proc that executes and outputs like this,

```
Plant1     Top1       12
Plant1     Bottom1    12
Plant1     Top2       14
Plant1     Bottom12   14
Plant2     Top1       34
Plant2     Bottom1    34
Plant2     Top2       18
Plant2     Bottom12   18
```

and I want it to be displayed like this in the Crystal Report.

```
Plant1
   Top
     Top1        12
     Top2        14
   Bottom
      Bottom1    12
      Bottom1    14

Plant2
   Top
     Top1        34
     Top2        18
   Bottom
      Bottom1    34
      Bottom1    18
```

I am thinking of grouping it by packing plant and then group it again to achieve this kind of output. Somebody there who can help me, PLease.

By the way, I am using Crystal Report 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) Create two groups.
2) Group one is based on the Plant1, Plant2, Plant3 etc
3) Create a formula filed, that checks your second field and output either Top, Bottom.
4) Now, Group 2 is based on your Formula (Bottom, Top)

Order:
Group 1 => Display Plant Stuff (In Group Header)
Group 2 => Display Location stuff (In Group Header)
Detail => Display the records
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to create the formula but Im stuck in making it. Could you please just give me a hint on how to do it. I will just try to understand and make as a guide for me to solve this project of mine. Thank you.